# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. provider: SSL Provider, error: 0

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, ado.net, database-connection

I have an exe which runs twice a day.
I am getting the error when the exe runs in the morning but works fine in the evening.

The exe generates logs and it logs the below error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL
>   Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)

I have also checked event viewer but no error is displayed related to above error.

We have checked the previous related posts, but the users seem to get the error continuously. But in our case, the exe runs fine at one time but gives error another time.

Any idea what might have gone wrong here?

Comment: Did you find a reason for this? I am facing the same problem